# which version control system is used in git development process

Tags: git, version-control

Most of us use git as a version control system, but i am asking Did the git community used any kind of VCS when they built the base of git system ? If yes, what was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#History):

> The development of Git began on 3 April 2005. The project was announced on 6 April, and became self-hosting as of 7 April.

So I'd say Git had always been developed using Git except for a very short period when it was just a tarball.

I should note that Git has been initially viewed by its creator, Linus Torvalds, as a very low-level set of tools to provide something like "versioned filesystem", upon which  higher-level tools, including VCSes, would build (that explains why Git was able to host itself so quickly: it had very rudimentary "hardcore-users-only" interface).  The history made a somewhat unexpected turn with Git having started accumulating features itself which eventually turned it itself into a full-blown VCS with high-level user interface etc.  Still, Git has its "versioned filesystem" concept in its core, available via a set of low-level tools.

Comment: The initial checkin to the [git repo for git](git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git) is dated 2005-04-07 15:13:13 -0700 (commit id `e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290`). The second commit, 3 minutes later, added copyright notices.

Comment: "*... except for a very short period when it was just a tarball...*" -- I don't know if it was ever a tarball before being self-hosted. Linus Torvalds likely didn't bother releasing it to anyone else in the 4 days before he made the first commit.

Answer (score 0):

Git is version-controlled in git (of course).

If you go far enough back in history, there was no git to store git, so there must have been something else until that point, but git has been in git for many years now.

Comment: I'd note to the OP that such a thing occurs quite commonly in the software field and is commonly called "bootstrapping": some tool (typically a programming language compiler/interpreter/transpiler) is first created using some other *already available* implementation and then usually eventually becomes "self-hosting" -- that is, being able to compile itself.  That way, say the C compiler of GCC happily builds itself, and then the compiled version of a newer compiler release is used to build its next release currently in the works.

Comment: Git, as a tool, is not really different: its version N is used to maintain the version N+1 currently in the works -- no magic at all.